# Combine values and insert to database field

Tags: php, sql

Hi what I'm trying to do is insert a time period value in my database which is **enrollperiod** and the format is:
**MONTH**+ **STRTDAY**+ **ENDDAY**, To get these values i have **3** text areas and combine them like so:

```
   $enrollp= $_POST['month'] . $_POST['strtday'] . $_POST['endday'];
```

(I'm not focused on SQL injections right now but don't worry iv'e read some PDO and prepared statement articles)

And i would insert this like so:

```
   $sql="Update tbl_enroll set enrollperiod='$enrollp'";
```

my problem is what data type should **enrollperiod** have?
and how should i be able to retrieve the value inside on **enrollperiod** and use is in this code:

```
     if (date('m') == '09' && date('d') == '12' &&  date('d') == '12' && $allowed)
```

The above line is not modified to check for the *start date* and *end date* I'm not sure how to perform it. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Curious to know about the constraints preventing you from storing the details in three different columns!

Comment: @Vikdor Yes i thought about that too just wan't to ask if its ok to combine time in a way.

Comment: Oh! okay. BTW, what would "week" contain? Start and end day are understood.

Comment: oh crapper that should be **MONTH** my bad editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every field (attribute) in a database relation (table) must be ATOMIC.

Why do you want to combine these values in one field? is there a logical reason for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use this format to store it in database:

week_strtday_endday

So after retrieving data from Database you could use `explode` function to split those 3 parts using the "_" character like this:

```
$array = explode('_', $field);
$week = $array[0];
$strtday = $array[1];
$endday = $array[2];
```

The type of field depends on the data that you are going to store, for example if the "week" is in range of 1-53 and the "strtday" and "endday" are in range of 1-7 then a VARCHAR(6) could be cool for that field.